# How to modify calculated field with TADODataSet?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe, tclientdataset, calculated-field, tadodataset

I have a `TADODataset` executed with (only for example):

```
SELECT id, name, lastname, name + ' ' + lastname as fullname
FROM persons
ORDER BY lastname
```

After I open the dataset, I can modify `"name"` and `"lastname"` fields, but can't modify`"fullname"`, because it's calculated.

I try to open `TADODataset` to `TClientDataset` via `DataProvider`, but it takes too long (there are about 100K records in source dataset):

```
SrcDS.FieldDefs.Update;
for i := 0 to Pred(SrcDS.FieldDefs.Count) do
  SrcDS.FieldDefs[i].CreateField(SrcDS).ReadOnly := false;
DestDS := TClientDataset.Create(nil);
DestDS.SetProvider(SrcDS);
DestDS.Open;
DestDS.SetProvider(nil);
```

All in all, i want to have an independent dataset with changeable fields.
How can i modify calculated fields in the dataset?

Comment: You want fullname to be editable - and then what? You can't write it back to the database (unless you parse it back into name and lastname in an event handler, which is error prone). What are you trying to accomplish with fullname?

Comment: I don't want to write it back to database. Dataset linked to TcxGrid component. I want change dataset on client only, so changes will be displayed in component.

Comment: You change the full name by changing its components... What's the use of allowing edit's to full name when you don't write them back? Unless would you be splitting the new full name and writing the split results to the first/last name fields? In that case: you'll have lots of fun with multi-cultural names.

Comment: It was only example to demonstrate calculated field

Comment: +1 This is a good question. I was trying to achieve the same behavior at some point. my conclusion was, it can't be done. even with `LockType = ltBatchOptimistic` you *could* edit the calculated filed, but I didn't find a way to tell the provider to *not* update changes made to the calc field during `UpdateBatch`.

Comment: You probably would need to undo all the changes on fullname before you do an `ApplyUpdates`. This way the provider would see that it don't need change anything. Another option would be use `onBeforeUpdateRecord` event handler of the DataSetProvider component to write your own SQL. See this [Building Applications With ClientDataSet and InterBase Express](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/27653), subtitle "Updating Datasets That Cannot Be Updated".

Comment: Also, very similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13505612/i-need-to-avoid-attempting-to-update-non-physical-fields-in-a-delphi-tclientdata?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

You have to calculated the field in Delphi. Create a new field by rightclicking on the TADODataset component, select `New Field`, give it a name and set it's type to 'calculated'.

In the OnCalculateFields-Event simply write:

```
Procedure TMyDataModule.MyDatasetCalculate(Sender : TDataset);
Begin
  MyDataSetFullName.AsString := MyDatasetFirstName.AsString+' '+MyDataSetLastName.AsString;
End;
```

Update: Regarding your second problem (100.000 records): If you load them into your ADODataset using LockType = ltBatchOptimistic, it will be fast enough and nothing is saved to the database, unless you call the `UpdateBatch` Method.

If this is still too slow, try using the async load feature (See the `ExecuteOptions`)

Comment: Sad, but true: i need to modify current dataset or fast create copy of it

Comment: "i need to modify current dataset or fast create copy of it" ?? What does that mean

Comment: Only modify dataset, not to write it back to database.

Comment: Ok, and you still want to e.g. change the first name and the full name automatically changes as well? Then you could use `LockType = ltBatchOptimistic` and finally discard/cancel the changes. But still have to do the field calculation in Delphi (naturally)

Comment: I don't need full name changes automatically anymore, only dataset with fields, which i can modify

Comment: @Tona, "Only modify dataset, not to write it back to database". You dont want to write "name, lastname" back to the DB? if yes, alzaimar gave you the correct answer.